# How do I find the next status and next date for a subscriber and offer?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I find the next status and next date for a subscriber and offer?

my table:

```
create table myTable ( user_id,offer_id,status,status_date) as
 select   1,offer_1,Active,01/01/2021 from dual union all
 select   1, offer_1,Deactive,01/01/2022  from dual union all
 select   1,offer_2,Active,02/01/2022  from dual
```

expected table:

| u_id | offer_id | status | status_date | next_status | next_status_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | offer_1 | Active | 01/01/2021 | Deactive | 01/01/2022 |
| 1 | offer_2 | Active | 02/01/2022 | null | null |

Comment: Please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it. It is a plain `join` with date restriction

Comment: What if the table has more than two rows per each `offer_id`?

Answer (score 0):

What do these dates represent? What is `02/01/2022`? 2nd of January, or 1st of February?

Anyway, outer join might help.

Setting date format (so that you'd know *what is what*):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from mytable;

   USER_ID OFFER_I STATUS   STATUS_DAT
---------- ------- -------- ----------
         1 offer_1 Active   01/01/2021
         1 offer_1 Deactive 01/01/2022
         1 offer_2 Active   02/01/2022
```

Query:

```
SQL> select a.user_id,
  2         a.offer_id,
  3         a.status,
  4         a.status_date,
  5         b.status next_status,
  6         b.status_date next_status_date
  7    from mytable a
  8         left join mytable b
  9            on     a.user_id = b.user_id
 10               and a.offer_id = b.offer_id
 11               and a.status_date < b.status_date
 12   where a.status = 'Active';

   USER_ID OFFER_ID   STATUS   STATUS_DATE     NEXT_STATUS     NEXT_STATUS_DATE
---------- ---------- -------- --------------- --------------- ----------------
         1 offer_1    Active   01/01/2021      Deactive        01/01/2022
         1 offer_2    Active   02/01/2022

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is all about activation date and deactivation date (could it be the same date?) - maybe this could help:

```sql
Select    t1.USER_ID, t1.OFFER_ID, t1.STATUS, t1.STATUS_DATE, t2.STATUS "NEXT_STATUS", t2.STATUS_DATE "NEXT_STATUS_DATE"
From      tbl t1
Left Join tbl t2 ON(t2.USER_ID = t1.USER_ID And t2.OFFER_ID = t1.OFFER_ID And t2.STATUS = 'Deactive')
Where t1.STATUS = 'Active'
```

With your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl (USER_ID, OFFER_ID, STATUS, STATUS_DATE) AS
        (
            select   1, 'offer_1', 'Active',    DATE '2021-01-01'  from dual union all
            select   1, 'offer_1', 'Deactive',  DATE '2022-01-01'  from dual union all
            select   1, 'offer_2', 'Active',    DATE '2022-02-01'  from dual
        )
```

The result is:

```sql
   USER_ID OFFER_ID STATUS   STATUS_DATE NEXT_STATUS NEXT_STATUS_DATE
---------- -------- -------- ----------- ----------- ----------------
         1 offer_1  Active   01-JAN-21   Deactive    01-JAN-22        
         1 offer_2  Active   01-FEB-22   Null        Null
```

Or you could use PIVOT

```sql
SELECT USER_ID, OFFER_ID, MIN(STAT) "STATUS", MIN(STAT_DAT) "STATUS_DATE", MAX(NEXT_STATUS) "NEXT_STATUS", MAX(NEXT_STATUS_DATE) "NEXT_STATUS_DATE"
FROM  ( Select    t1.USER_ID, t1.OFFER_ID, t1.STATUS, t1.STATUS "STAT", t1.STATUS_DATE, t1.STATUS_DATE "STAT_DAT"
        From      tbl t1  )
PIVOT ( MAX(STATUS_DATE) "STATUS_DATE", MAX(STATUS) "STATUS" FOR STATUS IN('Deactive' "NEXT") )
GROUP BY USER_ID, OFFER_ID
ORDER BY USER_ID, OFFER_ID

   USER_ID OFFER_ID STATUS   STATUS_DATE NEXT_STATUS NEXT_STATUS_DATE
---------- -------- -------- ----------- ----------- ----------------
         1 offer_1  Active   01-JAN-21   Deactive    01-JAN-22        
         1 offer_2  Active   01-FEB-22   Null        Null
```